# Gradle on m1 mac stuck when building android app

Tags: android, gradle, apple-m1

I have a m1 macbook air, when I try compile the app for android a Gradle daemon tries to start, however sometimes (very often) it will hang:

[image: gradle daemon stuck]

If I quit the process (via Cmd + C) and try to build the app again, then I get a message one gradle daemon cannot be re-used because it's busy and another one tries to start, which also hangs...

It's super annoying, anyone else facing this problem? I'm using azul JDK (because it runs native on arm), but I don't think this is a problem with java

When I run `./gradlew --status` that also hangs, the only solution seems to restart my machine a bunch of times

Comment: Are you using Room? If so this may be relevant: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174695268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the issue was Raycast, I started vscode from a script run by it (and ran the build command from the integrated vscode terminal), it seems gradle pipes the output of the daemons through the parent process and raycast doesn't play nicely with this model.

There 2 workarounds:

- Don't call gradle/android build from any subprocess (in my case raycast -> vscode), just a plain terminal will work
- Kill the parent process (again in my case raycast) before running the build command